# Why child element stick while using FlexBox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When i use

`.flex-container > div` to reach all child div elements and collect 3rd `div` with `.third`

and use

```
.third{
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  width:5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.third{
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div class="third">3</div>
</div>
```

it is not worked. I want to know why it is not working?

**Then i realize when i still use**

`.flex-container > div` to collect all child divs

and get rid of `margin-left: 1rem;`

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  width:5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  /* margin-left: 1rem; */
}

.third{
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div class="third">3</div>
</div>
```

it works. I want know why it acts like sticked?

When collecting all child divs with `.flex-container > *`  everything works perfectly

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.flex-container > * {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  width:5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.third{
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class="flex-container">
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div class="third">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `.flex-container>div` is a more direct selector than just `.third`.

Basically, `margin-left: auto;` is not applied to just `.third`.

**More on CSS-specificity**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

See below for an example with the selector `.flex-container>div.third`:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.flex-container>div.third {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class="third">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.third{
  margin-left:auto !important;
}` or this

Comment: That also works, but I would advise you to (almost) never use it. Using `!important` can complicate things in the future as it has priority over everything else. Better to fix it properly right away! :) @UPinar

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the behavior of the flex box. A flex box is very dynamic and can turn out differently depending on where it is used. Which means that you have to be very specific about an item in a flexbox to make sure that you mean exactly that one. For this reason, you can only address it as follows:

`.flex-container div:nth-child(3) { ... }`,

`#third { ... }`

`.container .third { ... }`

Comment: When i use `margin-left: auto` in flexbox, my brain thinks that i am not using `margin-left` property, it thinks  that i use a property which shoots an item to right. Than i realize they both are same :)

Comment: @UPinar You can also use `margin: 0 0 0 auto;` :-)

Comment: that is absolutely true sir :D